# How to write CSV data to file using Frends?

Tags: csv, frends

I faced with problem when i try to write CSV data to file.

I created data using `Frends Csv Csv Create` and then trying to write this data to the file using `Frends File File Write`.
[tasks results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqxVm.png)
[tasks results 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Q9V.png)

Main problem i can not see this data in file.

[data in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6bXo.png)
[settings of writing task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmD8g.png)

I tried write data in different ways, with `ToString()` and without. I tried to find another task for this goals. No result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the field type in the task File Write is in expression mode. I think that the field type is now Text or something else. You can also use double handlebars around the #result reference in that same task.

Comment: i just checked and can confirm that File Write is in expression mode.

Answer (score 0):

There was bug that in File Write task in Expression mode expression was grey color like in Text mode. Be careful with and double check it each time. Inputted data in Expression should be blue.